# PayPal IPN Data Not Returning

Tags: paypal-ipn

When using PayPal's IPN, does PayPal only return to you certain fields?  Or do they return all fields within the IPN return array?  I am trying to add a new field, specifically item_number1.  I noticed that it is arriving at PayPal, but the data is not returning to me.  Is there some backend setup I need to do to ensure this particular data point/variable is returned to me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this wasn't answered already...

IPN will return all fields.